# Optimization select group by

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    DC.variationID, COUNT(DISTINCT(DC.userID)) AS conversion
FROM 
    XXXX AS DC
WHERE 
    DC.testID = 'XXXX' AND DC.visit > 1
GROUP BY 
    DC.variationID
```

This is the description of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `XXXX` 
(
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `userID` bigint(17) NOT NULL,
   `testID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `variationID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `url` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `visit` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `isTestPage` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`testID`),
   KEY `url` (`url`),
   KEY `dc3_testIDPage` (`testID`,`url`),
   KEY `testid_istest` (`testID`,`isTestPage`),
   KEY `dc3_varIDPage` (`variationID`,`url`),
   KEY `index_rebond` (`testID`,`visit`,`variationID`),
   KEY `dc3_testIDvarIDPage` (`testID`,`variationID`,`url`),
   KEY `isTestPage2` (`variationID`,`isTestPage`,`visit`,`userID`),
   KEY `user_test_varID_url` (`userID`,`testID`,`variationID`,`url`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

This is the explain of the query

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'DC', NULL, 'ref', 'dc3_testIDPage,testid_istest,dc3_varIDPage,index_rebond,dc3_testIDvarIDPage,isTestPage2,user_test_varID_url', 'dc3_testIDvarIDPage', '8', 'const', '13695309', '33.33', 'Using index condition; Using where'
```

For me the query should use the index 'index_rebond' but unfortunatelly it not use it.I pretty sure that before the query use the index 'index_rebond'.

The query takes a lot of time to complete. Can you please tell me why the query doesn't use the index 'index_rebond' and what is the best way to optimize the query?

This is the result of show index

```
# Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment
'datacollect_v3', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '25909280', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '0', 'PRIMARY', '2', 'testID', 'A', '25909280', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'url', '1', 'url', 'A', '1657369', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_testIDPage', '1', 'testID', 'A', '2167', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_testIDPage', '2', 'url', 'A', '1850256', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'testid_istest', '1', 'testID', 'A', '3813', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'testid_istest', '2', 'isTestPage', 'A', '5721', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_varIDPage', '1', 'variationID', 'A', '2053', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_varIDPage', '2', 'url', 'A', '4171834', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'index_rebond', '1', 'testID', 'A', '1811', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'index_rebond', '2', 'visit', 'A', '11357', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'index_rebond', '3', 'variationID', 'A', '17208', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_testIDvarIDPage', '1', 'testID', 'A', '2049', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_testIDvarIDPage', '2', 'variationID', 'A', '3513', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'dc3_testIDvarIDPage', '3', 'url', 'A', '929052', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'isTestPage2', '1', 'variationID', 'A', '1891', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'isTestPage2', '2', 'isTestPage', 'A', '3309', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'isTestPage2', '3', 'visit', 'A', '16172', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'isTestPage2', '4', 'userID', 'A', '2712038', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'user_test_varID_url', '1', 'userID', 'A', '1103566', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'user_test_varID_url', '2', 'testID', 'A', '1336479', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'user_test_varID_url', '3', 'variationID', 'A', '1325388', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'datacollect_v3', '1', 'user_test_varID_url', '4', 'url', 'A', '16936138', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Best regards,

Comment: please format the explain output. Is this your real query? Why do I get the feeling that somethings have been left out? How long does it take to execute?

Comment: run a show index xxxxx and post the results here. the cardinality of the indices determines which index gets used and in some cases mysql will forgo using the index if the query addresses more than a third of the table.

Comment: this is the result of show index

Comment: Hi @e4c5 is my rel query is take 2hours and it still processing

Answer (score 1):

`PRIMARY KEY (id, testID)` does not make sense unless you are partitioning by `testID`.  Shouldn't you have `PRIMARY KEY (id)`?

If you have some combination of columns that is naturally unique, consider getting rid of `id` and using that combo as the PK.

This will be "covering", hence probably significantly faster:

```
INDEX(testID, visit, variationID, userID)
```

(And get rid of `index_rebond` since it will be redundant.)  `isTestPage2` is also covering (because the PK is included), but it is ordered inefficiently.

Unless you really expect to have more than 4 billion of the various ids, recommend you switch them to `INT UNSIGNED` (here and in the other tables).  Cutting this table and its indexes in half will help performance, especially if the dataset is too big to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the query optimizer prefer  dc3_testIDPage or  testid_istest because they also start with  testID

but you can force the use of an index

```
 SELECT DC.variationID, COUNT(DISTINCT(DC.userID)) AS conversion
                     FROM XXXX AS DC force index_rebond
                     WHERE DC.testID = 'XXXX' AND DC.visit > 1
                     GROUP BY DC.variationID
```